# Set administrative privileges in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, administrator

I have been writing many scripts using WMI and a lot of them only work if I start visual studio with "Run as Administrator".

Is there a way to set that programmatically with .Net or other means?

Eventually, these scripts will be run as .exes from Unity3D so I need to automate setting these rights before running them. Ideally I'm hoping this can all be done in C#.

Comment: If that were possible, it would be a huge security hole.

Comment: Run the scripts from a .bat with "runas.exe"?

Comment: You can specify in the application manifest that that application requires administrative privileges, but it will ask the user if they want to allow it.

Comment: look at this link based on Peter Ritchie's comment
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx

Comment: Good answers. Like I said I will be running in from Unity so could I run a batch file first setting the privileges and then use my scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments. The only way is to add a manifest file to your project that sets the required priviledges of your app to be administrative. Big thanks to Peter Ritchie and DJ KRAZE!